# MySQL PHP mysql_real_escape_string() - is this value not a string?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I am trying to update a record with the info from a multiple select box, I had it working fine when I was using INSERT INTO to add a new row, but now that I am trying to add it to this code that is using mysql_real_escape_string() it is returning the error message at the bottom of  this post. I presume it has something wrong with the value I'm trying to pass into it, but I don't know how to format it to make PHP happy!

```
 $query = "UPDATE studies
            SET strategies = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($strategies) . "' WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'"; 



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $strategylist = $row['name'];
    $strategyname = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
$pagelink = str_replace(" ","_",$strategylist);

    echo '<option value="<a href=&quot;strategies.php?strategy=' . $pagelink . '&quot;>'.$strategyname.'</a>" >' . $strategyname . '</option>' . '\n';
}
```

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 100 (that is the line above that starts SET strategies ='".....)

Comment: Can you post the code that assigns to $strategies and $id?

Comment: I think you need to check the code that sets $id and $strategies variables. Otherwise it's hard to tell which of them triggers an error. You should have included some relevant code prior to the query string generation.

Comment: Since it's faster try using the cast operator (int)$id or intval($id) instead of mysql_real_escape_string($id).

Comment: @lc & zingor - based on his question, it looks like he has a multi-select box named "strategies" and is using register_globals to get the $strategies variable.  Or something similar to that.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like $strategies is an array rather than a string.  Since you have a multi-select box, if they select multiple items, $strategies will come back as an array.

It comes down to how you want to store multiple selections in that single database column.  If you just want to append the selections together into one big string, then use implode():

```
// Sets strategies to a comma-separated list of selected strategies.
$query = "UPDATE studies
          SET strategies = '" . 
          mysql_real_escape_string(is_array($strategies) ? implode(',', $strategies) : $strategies) . "'
          WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'";
```

ETA:

As an aside, what you are doing here looks really scary.  You have an html link for a value on a select box option, which you are then storing in the database (presumably to display later?).

This is really opening yourself up for a trivial XSS attack where somebody submits a fake form with their own options containing links to an attack site, which you happily store in your DB and display later on your site.

Store an ID (or list of ids in your case) or something in your database, then build the links later when you need to display them.

Answer (score 0):

i think

$id is not string

```
mysql_real_escape_string($id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that $strategies/$id is an array and should be a string.